# Synchronize Sql Server databases without replication

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database-replication, microsoft-sync-framework

We are having difficulty deciding how to sync data between several Sql Servers (Express edition) and a central Sql Server (possibly also Express edition).

**Here's our scenario:**
We have 1-n clients that in normal operation mode do CRUDs to a central Sql Server. If that server goes offline they cache data until it comes back online. Now the data in the client(s) must be replicated somehow to that central Sql Server.
Data that gets sent therefore are never UPDATEs, it would only be INSERTs, and also never DELETEs.
**The replication is also one-way in this scenario.**

Is there a "cheap" way to synchronize the databases **without Sql Server data replication**, which is not available in the *Express* edition, and **without Sync Framework**, which requires the tables to be set up a certain way.

We're looking for a "poor man's" way to do this.

**Other notes:**

1. We use Entity Framework in the DAL to access the Sql server.
2. The amount of data that must be synced depends on the amount of traffic on the clients, and that data is all financial data.
3. The databases are the same, same  tables.

Comment: If you don't want to use the options you noted above, then you need to write something (code) that does it.

Comment: @Steve: or most likely **a whopping lot** of code .....

Comment: Take a crud at a time.  Read it from the local, write it to the central, delete it from the local.

Comment: When the client is "offline" does it need to be able to do selects or does it just need to queue up inserts?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain the client would write data to a local Sql Server when the central server is unreachable. It could be unreachable for not just hours but days. The client would need to "queue" its data in the local DB the nsomehow push them to central server when it comes back online.

Comment: @Steve "write a lot of code"? If you've done such a sync mechanism before, can you expand on that?

Comment: You did not answer my question, does the client need to ***read*** data or does it only perform writes to the DB

Comment: @John Yes I have. Using .Net, you can write it pretty generically by inspecting the schema of each table. The biggest thing for this is the need for some flag that tells you there was a change. We usually used an incrementing int every time a record changed. This allows you to compare records in both databases to find out which is newer... and also works great for concurrency.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain no it does not need to read. The sync is really only one-way (from the client to central server).

Comment: By cheap do you mean cheap on build time, cheap to make, cheap to maintain, cheap on performance? What's your real criteria here, and what skillset does your team posses? Custom building replication is not too big a deal but do you have a team that can build and maintain it? I would suggest a T-SQL option but I'm guessing your teams skills are in app development.